# React redux, ejecutar una acción a una API y retorna respuesta a la vista

Tags: reactjs, redux

Estoy teniendo un conflicto en como puedo acceder a la respuesta de la API.

Lo explico mejor:

Mi acción `newProfile` se encarga de enviar una petición a través de mi configuración de `apiAction` [(Detalle...)](https://github.com/ohansemmanuel/fake-medium/blob/master/src/actions/index.js)

```
// actions.js

export function newProfile(data) {
  return apiAction({
    url: '/profile',
    data,
    onSuccess: ((response) => ({ 
      type: NEWPROFILE,
      payload: response.id
    })),
    label: LOADING,
  });
}
```

Hasta aquí todo va perfecto, puedo ejecutar la acción sin problemas desde mi componente.

```
const act = props.newProfile(data); // act = undefined
```

Mi problema es que necesito ese `id` de la respuesta inmediatamente ya que después tengo que hacer un `history.push('/profile/' + act.id)`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi `onSuccess` retorne la respuesta a mi componente y a su ves mande al reducer `NEWPROFILE`.

> UPDATE

Estoy utilizando un custom middleware para el manejo de mi api, el cual produce un error al intentar crear una promesa

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Les dejo el enlace a mi configuración básica [github](http://github.com/nappalm/apiMiddleware/tree/main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El lenguaje *JavaScript* es orientado a eventos, es decir que cuando tú realizas una petición, no podrás obtener inmediatamente los resultados. En vez de eso, deberias de pasarle una función *callback* en los argumentos donde llamas a la función `newProfile`.

Quedaría:

```
newProfile(data, callback)
```

Cuando se llame al atributo `onSuccess`, llamarás a la función `callback` haciendo:

```
callback(response)
```

... y en tu código, llamarás a la función y harás algo como esto:

```
newProfile("lorem ipsum", (response) => { history.push(`/profile/${response.id}`})
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes implementar tu `action creator` como una promesa y utilizar el middleware [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) para solventar el `dispatch`, siendo así tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
// actions.js

export function newProfile(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => (dispatch) => {
        apiAction({
            url: '/profile',
            data,
            onSuccess: ((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: NEWPROFILE,
                    payload: response.id
                });
                resolve(response.id);
            }),
            label: LOADING,
        });
  });
}
```

Y en donde ejecutarías tu `dispatch` como una `promesa`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
props.newProfile(data).then((id) => {
    // Haz lo que desees con el id de la respuesta de la petición
});
```

Comment: Genial Jorius, Lamentablemente estoy utilizando un custom middleware para el manejo de mi api, me encataria que le echaras un ojo a mi configuración ya que al hacerlo como tu lo tienes me arroja un error `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`  te dejo el enlace a mi configuración básica https://github.com/nappalm/apiMiddleware/tree/main